# Hibernate - make id value be able to be autogenerated directly in datasource as well

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm making a Spring boot application with Hibernate ORM framework.

I have an `@Entity` class in my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thing")
public class Thing {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "thing_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private int price;
```

I successfully can persist a `Thing` to my datasource. And `thing_id` is generated as expected.

But I cannot insert a record directly in database manager (e.g. DataGrip):

```
insert into thing (name, price)
values ('aaa', 123);
```

I have a warning and appropriate error when trying to insert:

```
Following columns have no computed/default value and must be listed explicitly: thing_id
```

**So how can I make a column value autogenerated during insertion directly in database manager?**

Comment: Set a default value for the field (can be the next auto increment number) on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a numeric column that you want to auto-increment, it might be an option to set columnDefinition directly. This has the advantage, that the schema auto-generates the value even if it is used without hibernate. This might make your code db-specific though:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial") // postgresql

@Column(columnDefinition = "integer auto_increment") // MySQL
```